# How to uninstall OpenCV 2.4.9 completely from Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, opencv, software-uninstall

I want to integrate OpenCV with qt creator and for that OpenCV 3.0 is required.

I have OpenCV 2.4.9 already installed and want to uninstall it completely as it is causing problems in some functions. I would also like to know whether OpenCV 3.0 can be installed in 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: How did you install it? presumably not from the standard repository since 14.04 uses OpenCV-2.4.8

Comment: I downloaded it from opencv.org and it was installed perfectly after installing all the dependencies and it is working perfectly fine.But now I require OpenCV 3.0 and for that I need to uninstall this older version.

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar issue, but with version 2.4.8, I found this solution:

"So, to find all **OpenCV libraries**
1

`$> sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;`

The above command will find any file containing **opencv** in the name, and will prompt you to remove it. As always, be careful when deleting things manually!
That will take a hell of long time. Next I figure out that since I installed from compiling opencv from the source and used

`make install`

to create the install manifest, and then I pretty simple to use

`make uninstall`

Yes indeed it for sure clean up itself. Now I have a clean system to install the lates **opencv** release."

Works for me.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: thx for the observation

Comment: And an upvote!  +10 reputation!  ;-)

Comment: I am facing a similar situation. I ran that command and I deleted 10 or so libraries. The process ended in less that half a minute.  Furthermore do all the libraries contain "opencv" in their title?

Comment: If I know well, yes all library files have "opencv" in their name. You can double check by listing them: `pkg-config --libs opencv`.

Comment: Is there a modification to prevent prompting for confirmation? `rm: remove regular file '/usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.13'?`

Comment: Nvm. Figured it out: `sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -R {} \;` worked for me to prevent prompts

Answer (score 14):

This may be an easier way to go:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove opencv-doc opencv-data libopencv-dev libopencv2.4-java libopencv2.4-jni python-opencv libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-gpu2.4 libopencv-ts2.4 libopencv-photo2.4 libopencv-contrib2.4 libopencv-imgproc2.4 libopencv-superres2.4 libopencv-stitching2.4 libopencv-ocl2.4 libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml2.4 libopencv-video2.4 libopencv-videostab2.4 libopencv-objdetect2.4 libopencv-calib3d2.4
```

Comment: Seems this command more simple `sudo apt-get autoremove opencv-data
` I tried it with opencv 2.4.9 and ubuntu 14.04  , seems it delete everything I checked it with `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep opencv`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the synaptic package manager to remove all opencv libraries from your machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
yes | sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

is the command I used if long time process is to be skipped.

*Essentially it was asked in the comment and I could not repply to comment due to reputaions <50 as I am unable to login my account.*
**Caution:** The command contains `sudo` and it finds all the files with name opencv and deletes it. As the process:

```
sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

prompts for your permission for deleting any file, it takes a lot time.

```
yes |
```

just automatically inputs yes for all prompts.

> Caution: Its dangerous and only recommended for those who can bear any
>   potential file loss! It was asked, so I answered.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt remove libopencv*
```