# Uninstall OpenCV - Ubuntu keeps asking for permission

Tags: opencv

I am installing caffe and I think I screwed up my install by having multiple versions of OpenCV. Now I don't know what I did on my own but I might have done something wrong and nothing is working. So my safest bet is to do a complete uninstall of OpenCV.

I would then like to install OpenCV after that using conda. I followed this thread to completely uninstall opencv from ubuntu. [How to uninstall OpenCV 2.4.9 completely from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564290/how-to-uninstall-opencv-2-4-9-completely-from-ubuntu)

but when I type:

```
sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Ubuntu still keeps asking me for permission to remove every file.
How do I tell Ubuntu to remove it all without permission because there are a lot of files?

permission:

[image]

Comment: Please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick solution

Remove the `-i` flag from the `rm` command invoked from `find -exec`.

### Elegant solution

Don't use `-exec rm` at all but the `-delete` action of `find` instead.

### Advice for both cases…

You should probably run `find` without a destructive action like `-exec rm` or `-delete` first to verify that it won't delete precious files.

### What you really want…

is to uninstall a botched OpenCV installation. The deinstallation procedure depends on how it was installed in the first place. Please open a new question for that and line out how OpenCV was installed.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked ! Should have taken the elegant solution. I used the quick solution and I think I worsened my already ruined installation of caffe. Had to reinstall anaconda because I think I might have deleted some important files there.. wasn't able to install opencv via conda...Ah well, im a novice in ubuntu. Im bound to make even more mistakes. But thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `-i` flag in your command. Please make sure you want to remove all files whose names contain `opencv` before running the command.